# Using SQL DataSource

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, data-binding, gridview

I've a SQL DataSource and a Data Grid in a Web Page. The data grid gets binded automatically when the page is loaded. How do I delay that until click event of a Button.

Comment: @AmenAyach what will I do if I want to disconnect the bind at the click of another button.

Answer (score 1):

*In ButtonToBindclickevent*

- System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("BindUnbind")="b"
- response.redirect("Mypage.aspx")

*In ButtonToUnBindclickevent*

- System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("BindUnbind")="u"
- response.redirect("Mypage.aspx")

*in page_load*

if System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("BindUnbind")="b" then

- bind the grid

elseif System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("BindUnbind")="u" then

- UNbind the grid

endif

System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session("BindUnbind")=""